# Android Bluetooth LE notifications with 100Hz - missing calls

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android app which connects to a Bluetooth LE device and enables notifications for a specific characteristic. This characteristic notifies the Smartphone with 100Hz. So I assume, that the onCharacteristicChanged() method is called 100 times per second. But this is not the case!

- using Samsung Galaxy **S5** the onCharacteristicChanged() method is called 58 times per second = **42% data loss**
- using Samsung Galaxy **S5 mini** the onCharacteristicChanged() method is called 20 times per second = **80% data loss**
- using the **LG G3s** = **40% data loss**
- using the **LG G2 mini** = **0.5% data loss** (it's quite interesting that the G2 mini has the best "throughput" with its "low-end hardware" compared to the other Smartphones)

By using performance profiler I noticed that the LG G2 mini is the only Smartphone which has 6 Binders instead of 4. May be that's the reason why it is processing all notifications - but how can the number of Binders be increased?

Does anybody know, why Android doesn't call the onCharacteristicChanged() method 100 times per second?
Why are there such huge differences accross various phones?
**Is it possible to change something at the app or at the phone configuration to decrease the data loss?**

Thanks
Ben

Comment: 20 per second is still quite decent - its unclear why a system would be designed to support high rates.

Comment: hi, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. We are following now a completely different approach and we are not using a smartphone anymore.